# Python function returning "function" word pre-fix and "at 0x110257760" post-fix

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I'm using python selenium to return a session name with driver.execute_script

```
    def session_name(func_name):
        return driver.execute_script('browserstack_executor: {"action": "setSessionName", "arguments": { "name": " %s " } }' % func_name)


    session_name(my_function_name)
```

it gives me `function my_function_name at 0x110257760` as output. I was just expecting `my_function_name`.

I can't understand why? I searched for answers but can't seem to find them. What is a concept I'm missing here?